# How to compile the Raw Haskell bindings to OpenCV aka GitHub member arjuncomar's OpenCV-Raw repo

Tags: c++, c, opencv, haskell, wrapper

Arjuncomar states in the OpenCV-Raw  readme.md at this link https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv-raw/blob/master/README.md

### "Compilation / Installation

Compiling this package might be a little tricky at the moment since I've only had the chance to test it on my machine so far. First, you need to generate C wrappers for the version of OpenCV on your machine -- this repo holds the wrappers for OpenCV 3.0 (HEAD) only. You can generate these wrappers (and the corresponding Haskell bindings) via:

```
./setup.sh <path to opencv headers>
```

e.g.

```
./setup.sh /usr/local/include"
```

I ran './setup.sh /usr/local/include', in the root directory of Opencv-Raw, btw I have OpenCV 2.4.7 installed on Ubuntu Saucy 64-bit and I get this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "cbits/genhsc.py", line 161, in <module>
 cgen.gen(header_dir, headers, dstdir)
 File "/home/w/Documents/opencv-raw-master/cbits/genc.py", line 367, in gen
 self.readHeaders(header_dir, srcfiles)
 File "/home/w/Documents/opencv-raw-master/cbits/genc.py", line 350, in readHeaders
 decls = parser.parse(header_dir + hdr)
 File "/home/w/Documents/opencv-raw-master/cbits/hdr_parser.py", line 732, in parse
 f = open(hname, "rt")
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp'
```

Arjuncomar states "this repo holds the wrappers for OpenCV 3.0 (HEAD) only." so  I tried to find an OpenCV 3.0 download but no luck and I've never seen a core.hpp file in /usr/local/include so don't really understand error. I'm trying to  incoroporate the autogenerated C wrappers for OpenCV's C++ interface  arjuncomar wrote in his haskell bindings into my own OpenCV wrapper for a different language (minus the haskell part of course) and I felt this might be a good first step but if I can just make a make file for this code i/e

the cpp file

```
void cv_imshow(String* winname, Mat* mat) {
    cv::imshow(*winname, *mat);
}
```

the hpp file

```
void cv_imshow(String* winname, Mat* mat);
```

and expect it to be a perfect C wrapper for C++ OpenCV code pls let me know...and if posible a link regarding how to make such a make file posted here would aid greatly....I'm used to C but new to C++/ C++ MakeFiles and would rather do this perfect on my first try so I can output volume more quickly without worrying about making an error...

....Any help is appreciated...A good day=) to you All...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out just buld Arjun Comars fork here https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv and the bindings will be autogenerated in the  opencv_generated cpp and hpp files

Answer (score 2):

I'm the library author. The library has been moved a couple of times after requests from the OpenCV folks. It's currently sitting in my fork of the [opencv_contrib repo](https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv_contrib). Follow the instructions in the readme to build and install the wrappers.

The procedure amounts to setting up an opencv build directory, having `cmake` populate it by telling it where the opencv source tree is located and that it needs to load the extra modules from opencv_contrib.

```
cd <cmake build directory>
cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=<opencv_contrib>/modules <opencv_source_directory>
```

Compiling and installing the library will install the C wrapper headers to "/include/opencv2/c/" and the compiled binary to "/lib/libopenc_c.so". If `cabal` and `ghc` are present on the system, it will also compile and install the Haskell bindings. For me, this is as simple as:

```
make -j6 && sudo make install
```

Building in this manner should avoid the issue listed in the OP because the headers are pulled by `cmake` from the source tree and passed directly to the header parser and wrapper generator. Please send bug reports to either the [opencv_raw repo](https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv_raw) or to [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/arjuncomar/opencv_contrib). I'm watching both repos and I'm always happy to take pull requests.

Edward -- I understand you're trying to get in touch with me. You can reach me at nrujac `at` gmail `dot` com or directly on github by opening an issue on any of repos.